# The requested script resource 'Seadragon.Seadragon.Config.js'

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

i currently updated my site asp.net 3.5 to 4.0. now i have found little problem when my site runs i found this error :

```
The requested script resource 'Seadragon.Seadragon.Config.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The requested script resource 'Seadragon.Seadragon.Config.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: The requested script resource 'Seadragon.Seadragon.Config.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.]
   System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +469796
   System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +213
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts) +202
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +444
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +122
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8872106
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2716


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: can u give me nutget command to resolve this problem.

Comment: i already have this version ajax toolkit Version - 4.1.7.1213

Comment: can you please edit your question with your aspx page, especially the `<%@ Register Elements` would be important

Comment: i already mention this line in web config `<controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have another version of the toolkit installed. Check your "packages" folder if you are using nuget

Answer (score 0):

I comment the line on web.config

```
add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
```

It works for me.